# Websocket using Stomp not able to receive subscribe data in client

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

I am using websocket with spring boot and stomp messaging protocol, where i created a HTML and using javascript event listener code to publish and subscribe the data. I can see publisher data in network tab and i can process the request in java as well. but subscriber data not showing. could any one help on this?

Comment: please provide code example about the problem ...

Comment: Found solution. I included wrong path for the subscriber that is why the response wasn't broadcasted.